# Is there a way/ubuntu program to glue a bunch of program windows together into one window?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

While developing, I like to keep a browser, and code editor open on the same screen. I'd like to find some way to join them and treat them as a single window, so they minimize together, and resize together, and have a movable divider between them.

Is there some sort of window-panel application that I can use to create a multi-program window?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a tiling window manager. Combine one with [thkala's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8874055/200291) and you'll probably have what you want.

Comment: And I thought MDI was supposed to be dead!

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks--I couldn't remember the name for this.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I had a better idea of what to search for now. I googled tiling window manager for ubuntu and came up with xmonad. Any thoughts? I might try it on monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't have access to comments on this site yet; guess the points system is separate from stackoverflow.

Wanted to respond to OP's last comment.  I really like xmonad.  You can set it up to run within gnome, kde, etc. with extensions. Here are steps I took in gnome 2.28.2:

```
sudo yum install -y xmonad.x86_64
sudo yum install -y ghc-xmonad-contrib.x86_64
sudo yum install -y ghc-xmonad-contrib-devel.x86_64
```

Create a file ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs and put in:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome
main = xmonad gnomeConfig
```

Set the window manager:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager xmonad
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/applications/window_manager/current xmonad
```

If you change your mind, you can run the above two commands, substituting xmonad with metacity to put it back as it was.

links:

[xmonad in Gnome](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome/)

[xmonad in KDE](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_KDE/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it can be done with Gnome (or Unity), but you can definitelly do it with the Fluxbox WM, as [named like tabs](http://fluxbox.org/features/).

Another option is [KDE's tabbed windows](http://www.freetechie.com/blog/kde-4-4-beta-1-tabbed-windows-review-opensuse/). IIRC PWM and PekWM can do it too.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not exactly what you want, but if your window manager does not provide support for this, you might be able to use an [Xnest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xnest) instance instead.

Xnest is essentially a nested X server that outputs to a window, rather than a hardware device. You can run specific applications, or even a full-featured desktop within an Xnest window.

Unfortunately, this approach is slightly cumbersome: applications need to be launched with a non-default display option (or a modified `DISPLAY` environment variable) and you cannot move windows into or out of the Xnest window.