# Dual page view in MuPDF?

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-reader

I am really liking using [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/). Is there a way to enable a dual page view? Or, does it just display whatever was the original formatting/specification during the creation of the PDF?

Comment: I don't know much of this app, but seems like that this feature is not implemented. Your best chances may be that you donate small amount and request feature or try to modify source code yourself and contribute to project you like.

Comment: Simple answer is "No, it does not support that.", at least that there is no mention of dual page view on [the manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/mupdf.1.html) and a quick glimpse at the source code seems to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I had checked the manual, but did not see it either. At this time, I am not familiar enough to check the source code, so thanks for the note on that.

Comment: Here is [the source](https://mupdf.com/releases/index.html), the [git repo](https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=summary), and the [contact page](https://artifex.com/contact/mupdf-inquiry.php).  We should all send them a message, asking that they implement that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, it does not support that (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I really like muPDF too, and wish it would natively support dual pages.

At the moment **I am just running two instances off the same file and flipping both pages each time** - annoying but works for pdfs that are laid-out with facing pages.

Thinking about trying to automate this with an alias to start two instances and then a script that updates the other instance when I change pages on the first. Now that I write it out it sounds clunky ... perhaps someone has an idea?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1085734)

Answer (score 1):

MuPDF in windows format, is the core Screen Rendering Engine for SumatraPDF (Which I support). It reputedly works well in Wine but unknown how well current version behaves.

On its own SumatraPDF has no split single view. It has tear off tabs and separate panes but no glue to keep two parts together. (This was and still is possible in a Web Framed viewer). Here is a commercial app borderline flouting the licensing conditions by running unbundled inside a pay ware!

[image]

### Back to the OP Question

it might be possible for MuPDF using say an Ubuntu window manager see

[Is there a way/ubuntu program to glue a bunch of program windows together into one window?](https://superuser.com/questions/378829/is-there-a-way-ubuntu-program-to-glue-a-bunch-of-program-windows-together-into-one)

Comment: Here is [the source](https://mupdf.com/releases/index.html), the [git repo](https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=summary), and the [contact page](https://artifex.com/contact/mupdf-inquiry.php).  We should all send them a message, asking that they implement that functionality.